# QGIS/proj errors with EPSG:2951

Tags: qgis, proj, osgeo4w

I've built various QGIS projects that use Canadian UTM and MTM CRS. They worked just fine in QGIS versions through 3.8 (based on proj4 and ?proj5).

In QGIS windows version 3.10.0-3, things got borked with the transition to proj6. QGIS version 3.10.1 seems to have largely fixed that, after I manually also installed `proj-datumgrid-north-america` in OSGeo4W. My maps display fine again, with CRS conversion on the fly, without pop-up errors.

However, my QGIS message log silently displays the following, with the so-called critical errors repeating during any map redraws. (EPSG:2951 is my project CRS. It's NAD83 (CSRS) MTM zone 9.)

```
2019-12-11T10:39:56     CRITICAL    Cannot normalize transform between EPSG:2951 and EPSG:4326
2019-12-11T10:40:04     CRITICAL    Cannot normalize transform between EPSG:4326 and EPSG:2951
2019-12-11T10:40:04     CRITICAL    Cannot normalize transform between EPSG:3857 and EPSG:2951
2019-12-11T10:40:04     CRITICAL    Cannot normalize transform between EPSG:26918 and EPSG:2951
```

Now (3.10.1), the maps *look* normal, but I'm still surprised at critical errors, even if silent ones. Should I be worried, and if so what should I do?

Comment: You shouldn't need a grid file to convert between CSRS and WGS84. EPSG has 2 transformations, both self-contained. There isn't one between NAD83 and NAD83 (CSRS) (26918 and 2951). I with I had an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. It was a bug, which has Nyall Dawson has [fixed](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/33370) after I raised it as an [issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33367). The fix is present in version 3.11.0-40+.